# Use Django REST API and Django Templating

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I'm just starting to use Django for my backend services, but I'm a bit confused about the usage of Django REST framework, see I'm building an iOS app as a front-end, to the best of my knowledge Django REST is the best library to perform my backend tasks, however, I would eventually like to build a regular web front-end. I've seen tutorials on Django and Django REST, and they never talk about using both.

My question is how to use Django REST to feed the iOS App, and be able to use Django's templating engine for a web front-end using the DRY principle.

I did read on the Django REST framework's website, that you can use `class based` views with the framework, so can I use this same class to feed by web front-end and my ios app efficiently?

```
class SnippetDetail(APIView):

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
```

Comment: It's possible to use both the API and the templating system but you'll need to write separate views for both.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Thanks, that clears things up!

Comment: you can use front-end framework like react ,nextjs ,vue ....